# Katalon Studio to take screenshots from PDF file pages

Tags: java, groovy, pdfbox, katalon-studio

There are some PDF files, which pages should be captured to images to make input for a text recognizer. It should takes screenshots from all of the pages and save also textual content. I use following script, but it takes only text and gives error for some pdf files:

Groovy script:

```
package com.pdf.reader

import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

import internal.GlobalVariable

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ReadPdfFromBrowser {

    PDDocument pdDoc;

    @Keyword
    public String PdfReaderUtil(String html, WebDriver driver){

        String pdfFileInText = "";

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        URL url = new URL(html);
        BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(
                url.openStream());

        pdDoc = PDDocument.load(fileToParse);
        pdDoc.getClass();

        if (!pdDoc.isEncrypted()) {

            PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

            PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

            pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        }
        driver.close();
        return pdfFileInText;
    }
}
```

Testcase:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import internal.GlobalVariable

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(GlobalVariable.url)
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl()

def pdf = CustomKeywords.'com.pdf.reader.ReadPdfFromBrowser.PdfReaderUtil'(url, driver)
File file = new File(GlobalVariable.fajlNev)

def lines = pdf.split("\\r?\\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    file << line;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Error message in some cases(in case of some pdf files):

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at com.pdf.reader.ReadPdfFromBrowser.invokeMethod(ReadPdfFromBrowser.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:50)
    at print.run(print:10)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1578224744400.run(TempTestCase1578224744400.groovy:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1124)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2603)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2574)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:219)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1222)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1122)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument$load.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.pdf.reader.ReadPdfFromBrowser.PdfReaderUtil(ReadPdfFromBrowser.groovy:46)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Your Input is empty or not a PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : This code should generate a txt, but I don't get it.

Comment: Your code doesn't get so far, it fails at opening your (alleged) PDF. You need to check what really gets loaded. I suggest you copy the content of `fileToParse` into a local file and then look what's there. Maybe it is a "not found" HTML page and not a PDF? Or completely empty? `IOUtils.copy()` can copy an input stream to e.g. a FileOutputStream (don't forget to close) so you can have a look what's there. (Are you new at java? If yes, don't hesitate to say so)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : Yes, fileToParse variable is empty in case of this pdf. Text in this pdf cannot be copied and print function is disabled too. Could it be problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: With "empty" I mean zero length. That isn't a PDF. PDF is a binary format that starts with %PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : Please check this file: https://gofile.io/?c=WYPqpZ It starts with %PDF-1.4, but I am unable to get text from it or screenshot it with method above.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : Hosted example file: http://aplaidshirt.epizy.com/samplePDF.pdf

Comment: Both PDFs are file, I can open them with PDFDebugger. The problem must be when getting it from an URL. Maybe the MIME type on the server isn't set correctly, or maybe there is a HTML page instead. Did you create the PDF file like I suggested, or did you just upload the file from your disk drive?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : It was a standard pdf, which was processed by an anti-copy software. I uploaded that file to server. It works on the same way in prod too. So format is given, but it is a pdf.

Comment: What pdfbox version are you using? Have you tried to load the PDF not from an URL but directly from a file?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : I use version 2.0.18 and downloading is not on option,it is disabled in prodcution. PDF is accessible only from URL.

Comment: Then we're back to what I wrote before - find out what is really read from that URL.